# i want to make a notification when my position is near to a pin xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

i want to make a notification when my position is near to a pin xamarin.
and i have tried .

```
foreach (Pins a in listpin)
             {
                 double d = Location.CalculateDistance(a.Positionlat, a.Positionlon, MyLocation().Result, DistanceUnits.Kilometers);
                 DisplayAlert("Alert", $"{d}", "OK");
                 if (d < 1)
                 {
                     SendNotification();
                 }
             }
```

when i run the app the screen stays white and the display alert don't work please help.

Comment: don't do `MyLocation().Result`, instead determine your location **before** you enter the loop, and be sure you use await with async calls

Comment: `public async Task<Location> MyLocation()` to get the result i have to do `MyLocation().Result` and i have determine my location before the loop and it doesn't work , and i think the problem is from the funtion MyLocation

Comment: please learn how to use async/await.  "i think the problem is from the funtion MyLocation" - there is no way for us to help you with that because you haven't posted the code for `MyLocation`

Comment: Thank you fo your help but i have found the solution :), yeah i changed `MyLocation().result` by `await MyLocation`